# В каких местах нужно поставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

> В тексте старуха Уми живущая на вершине горы Ай-Петри вдали от людей седьмой год подряд напевает одну и ту же песню.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

*В тексте старуха Уми — **живущая на вершине горы Ай-Петри, вдали от людей**, — седьмой год подряд напевает одну и ту же песню.*

**Вставка** для определения: два тире, вторая запятая относится к вставке (уточняющее обстоятельство).

Без вставной конструкции **нет знаков:** *В тексте старуха Уми / седьмой год подряд / напевает одну и ту же песню.*

Comment: Вставил свой ответ в качестве дополнения к вашему. А на ваш ответ я плюс поставлю, мне нравится такой вариант.

Comment: Если что-то из моего ответа вставите в свой, разрешаю, т. к. мой ответ — это просто дополнение к вашему.

Comment: Спасибо, Максим. Варианты есть, только идеала нет. Много запятых – читать сложно.  Причастный оборот распространить? Но с одними запятыми тоже читается не лучшим образом.  Если для школы, то и ничего.  А для худ. текста лучше все же вставка, как мне думается.

Comment: Вопросов нет. Просто вы сказали про подлежащее, а Александр про сказуемое. То есть одно в одном ответе, а другое в другом, а два ответа принять нельзя.

Comment: Я принял ваш ответ. Про подлежащее могу согласиться с вами, я тоже так считаю. А почему вас огорчило то, что вы ответили по моей просьбе? А что вас тогда интересует, если не принятие? Очень-таки охота знать, что вы имели в виду над этими словами.

Comment: И всë-таки? Если вы, конечно, хотите рассказать об этом.

Comment: Рассказала бы, но это частный разговор не для всех.  Надо удалять такие беседы, ведь никакой ценности для форума лингвистов они не имеют.  Лучше уж обсуждать интонацию и логические ударения.

Comment: @Максим Кстати, про приемку ответа я сначала вообще не говорила. Но спросила у вас: почему вы никак не обозначили свое отношение к ответу, Согласны или не согласны. Комментариев никаких не было.  А неясным я считала вопрос о подлежащем (контекстуально несвободные сочетания обычно оцениваются неоднозначно).

Answer (score 0):

Дополню.

Можно ещë два способа использовать:

*В тексте старуха Уми, живущая на вершине горы Ай-Петри вдали от людей, седьмой год подряд напевает одну и ту же песню* — обособляется причастный оборот *живущая на вершине горы Ай-Петри вдали от людей*;

*В тексте старуха Уми, живущая на вершине горы Ай-Петри, вдали от людей, седьмой год подряд напевает одну и ту же песню* — причастный оборот теперь выглядит так: *живущая на вершине горы Ай-Петри*, а *в дали от людей* — обособленное обстоятельство.

Обстоятельство *вдали от людей* можно как выделять запятыми, так и нет. Если автор хочет подчеркнуть смысл оборота, то он выделит запятыми. (Или же если автор может выделить запятыми **для пояснения**. А если не подчëркивает автор оборот, то он не будет выделять его.

---

Данный ответ я написал, только чтобы дополнить ответ Sharon.